# How do you enable SSH on a new raspbian Jessie image without a keyboard/monitor?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

Looks like SSH is disabled by default on all new Jessie images.  I only run Pi's headless with SSH, so I have no way to configure a new Pi without a keyboard/monitor (which I don't have).

Newsgroups/articles say just 'put a file called "SSH" into the /boot/ folder, but how can you do this from windows?

Is there a way to do this (enable SSH) on the SD card, then insert it into the Pi, then SSH to the new IP address?

Comment: If you plug the SD card into your Windows PC - using a card-treader if you don't have a suitable slot, you will be able to see the `/boot` partition because it is FAT32 formatted.

Comment: Just use the [Raspbian Jessie Lite image](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest) SSH should be enabled by default - since it's headless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/raspberry-pi/8355/enable-ssh-on-raspbian#t=201702162158137000932

Comment: @Mark: my mistake; I was looking for a root folder named 'boot', where the documentation meant the root of the drive for the SD. Thanks

Comment: @Cicero: SSH is disabled by default starting with the November 2016 release.

Comment: By the way, you can also put a `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `/boot` so that your wifi connects too.

Comment: @user3235770 Why would they do that on Lite images?? and regardless - wouldn't it just be easier to download a pre november release then and upgrade it once you're on it? - rather than editing img files.

Comment: @Cicero Good question. I came across a Pi Foundation page that said they disabled by default it 'for security reasons.' Can't find it today.

Comment: @user3235770 If this is the [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/) it's **only** the regular Raspbian Image with Pixel, **not** the Raspbian Lite Image

Comment: I think you can find more on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . It is specifically for Raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

For enabling ssh first with without keyboard/monitor you need to create an empty ssh file inside SD card.

```
touch ssh
```

I used following link:
    https://www.installvirtual.com/enable-ssh-in-raspberry-pi-without-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

After copying the image onto the SD card:
On a Linux computer with SD card slot the boot partition of the SD card is 
normally automatically mounted as `/media/`*yourusername*`/boot`.  In this
case you could simply execute the following command:

```
touch /media/`id -un`/boot/ssh
```

to create an empty file called ssh in the `boot` directory of the SD card.
After unmounting the SD card and putting it back into a Pi the SSH service
should start fine after boot.
Verified using `2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie.zip` and a laptop with SD card slot running the Ubuntu LTS Linux version 14.04.
Creating an empty file with name `ssh` in the FAT32 boot partition should be
also possible using a laptop running Windows.